# How to get the range of tokens for only particular CF in cassandra by CQL?

Tags: cassandra, column-family, nosql

I do want to repair a column family part by part using the command nodetool repair -st starting_token -et ending_token. As each row in column family have different range of token values,Is there any way to get the different token range possessed by that single column family in CQL?

Answer (score 2):

So here's how this works.  Token ranges are assigned per node, and each column family is present on every node.  The rows end up on the nodes that are responsible for the range(s) containing with the hashed token values of their partition keys.

Essentially you'll need to run the following on each node:

```
SELECT tokens FROM system.local;
```

If you are using vNodes, you will get multiple tokens back.

```
aploetz@cqlsh> SELECT tokens FROM system.local;

 tokens
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {'-1091112185956497009', '-1164785492893427439', '-1167829617851670918', '-1171799320814514438', '-1220659011520889145', '-1250811487550948315', '-1297928892760846227', '-1435486410979260914', '-159983009635394649', '-160297953493203374', '-1613145765236390736', '-1676849977967938947', '-1756370653624218439', '-1835623956489395606', '-1972676396564362720', '-2105581158970623941', '-2113102006411307206', '-2119271205810062909', '-2186391474573271666', '-2251714694071564612', '-2311228696396266537', '-2340780087732616527', '-2351113368330821782', '-2391361579096454359', '-2397576612078334999', '-240295711752074087', '-2430168272535883900', '-2454459606957813499', '-2578215631564011319', '-2670523761816295704', '-2741937555731412354', '-2838644256454453334', '-2853505195999767446', '-2896364007728546373', '-3011169167697871944', '-3139031544096567248', '-3172364675903486270', '-3321048874466575263', '-3403553389012707961', '-3434553225711366588', '-3572662857095132919', '-363478820117216992', '-3731342886172688324', '-3828738970047814629', '-3923108115921574041', '-4207719290671127784', '-4213450692973207157', '-4267918498623169747', '-4454313210548542774', '-4522089243118260180', '-4686813932319880327', '-4706851456933781766', '-476503825203776548', '-4818827732816962114', '-4884244926730440457', '-4893761698469396503', '-4927791739609341217', '-5118863279132713782', '-5222012706931411855', '-5278077620509881468', '-5308381452139766226', '-5314994836763115825', '-5362304406668986552', '-5424203844337117235', '-5540862450054061634', '-5575809028025622186', '-5586794452636345367', '-5602142658183977000', '-5957940090332092145', '-6053820169278517216', '-6061992137397227157', '-6092700717400860234', '-6098814915556913235', '-6125140994217978293', '-6182520240773909693', '-6490078469312436139', '-6503830582918931553', '-6507816331425960290', '-6593543713795155450', '-665402151939687808', '-6665250539682398132', '-6686925174596784152', '-6686936813469873659', '-6745516062262361156', '-6751543150888578355', '-676252197383255342', '-6812345257628741468', '-6853257753738957834', '-6994371495414421744', '-7039925342217018971', '-7105683738550921678', '-7187207923640032590', '-7231500587510716480', '-7242384386953981903', '-7268287721816055091', '-7269193738744493125', '-730297388764867390', '-7321840331190515837', '-7402256096406491174', '-7557335263193149955', '-7643508291844672829', '-7646260662430183442', '-7730090754788564211', '-7933895828383338062', '-8006101251639669970', '-8160111984163926559', '-8239712536730591036', '-8281401629687124869', '-8551415314002837476', '-8617041009484239200', '-8744311014159914197', '-8757249516175714465', '-8881610205473044780', '-8950454440261645632', '-8960058874057749692', '-8990476941757805791', '-9027625467994607492', '-9096025406772005927', '-9151816479244101233', '-9168132882357919327', '1001240966668670688', '1020967134038597894', '1042342699529284986', '122794649946272503', '1264727650693681745', '1290221752263277667', '1615048471076227389', '168018199437622656', '1682039572636542209', '1777487075321359912', '1872103228708991914', '1872106441509198597', '190050335935594413', '1953586489815614452', '1980083434374789459', '1989646097018964280', '1997493003521864542', '2133394076575157069', '2162236128829210715', '2205582124024318034', '2368514429906336132', '2382462092762414737', '2390778206816580696', '2498644969624256680', '2509049419296323930', '2572433245039568340', '258471805271633826', '2608159533870363981', '2720871503082469250', '2771716043476204853', '2921859435174076699', '2970359208379667080', '3005875557399969026', '3073068751352084288', '3206576185784519256', '3279781621811765505', '3329722134256886344', '3351465824702929208', '3392544574559052348', '346284560178092463', '3506924470614314291', '3588769157576738975', '3640895738060174823', '3671593567932108709', '369685344793361296', '3723404105953315561', '3736948331163861381', '3793014921940938366', '4054193920546769504', '4059437525355871115', '4090247491753203973', '4138146104743855579', '416339413219965914', '4174048518689692629', '4201707112290041877', '4223903037491863750', '4313240638476747660', '4381827743949927168', '446416919294987678', '4466723365750401122', '4488814416970401346', '4787969571148381116', '4961931969817821147', '5042391116365066139', '5060174813905827355', '5109059643853384862', '5309310666801662767', '5338885912454964515', '539331166254795852', '545123987321907570', '5544176546905284316', '5564799391324118158', '5642806421926957573', '5695678799850801479', '5732617448649783934', '5828583767862167950', '5897481846800563368', '5942045763609991848', '5953719545203584087', '5985866273791752417', '603883240501916601', '6067381087563667880', '6136850536765674822', '6217116270398566984', '6219430136349515748', '6263473589234478296', '6271396513976329660', '6310190792450345888', '6311258786031568465', '6391631478802878832', '6512262985538553264', '6517953526395551831', '6571795146245594380', '6579909409501407291', '6658893626149294568', '6700093808424149299', '672414419684375725', '681853090855133689', '6825404174655448644', '6884570112171278511', '6902221479980422101', '6917022145170102921', '6949262670840023002', '6970834046862436050', '7021436833411712933', '7065637357528915339', '7170649662657474866', '7362654168816474438', '7435307601634705143', '7476428884939065895', '7544734890164992109', '7586820764813582018', '7702300782985576048', '7708413084490663940', '7714051593135405191', '7753625153778981572', '7768798568945491480', '7815598075349722381', '7944744316446841036', '7947962600829308115', '8040181689514250853', '8076381733885447081', '8106230831043606976', '8109599641703632474', '8163633143520569902', '8211216498472695489', '8650991370450706548', '8661072640844147365', '871927125181804354', '8737402779133986348', '8750908089533366569', '8754412440211083493', '8856834458340018893', '890116053292621739', '9050714841124764568', '997718044153409043'}

(1 rows)
```

So in this case, to repair `stackoverflow.test_table` for the first range listed, it would look something like this:

```
$ nodetool repair -st -1091112185956497009 -et -1164785492893427439 stackoverflow test_table
```

Comment: system.token returns tokens for whole node.But I am in need of tokens which are responsible only for particular CF so that I can able to repair the CF part by part.  

If I do ,

nodetool repair -pr keyspace CF,

The log shows the ranges of starting and ending token, where the repair has been carried out.Please let me know,If there are any other ways to get  
that ranges so that I can easily repair CF part by part.